# How to Boost::serialize a hashmap of vectors?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I have a core data structure that I am loading values into: it is a hashmap of vectors. The vectors contain a struct, however.  Further, the struct uses a template type.

I need to serialize this data structure and save to the disk periodically.  Then, later--in a different program--I need to load the serialized data structure.

Here is a streamlined version of the structs.  I minimally define them, but there are other data items (members), in addition to this bare bones version.

```
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<map>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct DataUnit{
    size_t time;
    string transaction_string;
    T transaction;             
}

template<typename T>
struct DataStructure{
    map<string transaction_hash, vector<DataUnit<T>> > hashmap;
    int max_transactions;

    // I have a method to add stuff, but omitted for readability
}
```

---

I started with the first struct, `DataUnit` and modified it as follows:

```
    template<typename T>
struct DataUnit{
    size_t time;
    string transaction_string;
    T transaction;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version){
        ar & time;
        ar & transaction;
        ar & transaction_string;
    }
};
```

Eventually, I need to serialize the data structure. However, when I run just this with the following code:

```
int main(){
    DataUnit<int> hi;
    hi.time = time(NULL);
    hi.transaction = 1;
    hi.transaction_string = "world";
    return 0;
}
```

The world blows up with errors from boost.  As far as I can tell, I followed the tutorial example [exactly](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html).  How do I boost-serialize these objects?

Some of the errors (but there are so many I can't believe it isn't something fundamental...):

> In function `boost::archive::text_oarchive::text_oarchive(std::ostream&, unsigned int)
>
> undefined reference to `boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl::text_oarchive_impl(std::ostream&, unsigned int)'
>
> last error:
>
> undefined reference to `boost::archive::archive_exception::~archive_exception()'

and it goes on from there...but I don't see where I have lacked any includes...(boost was installed via Cygwin)...

(running the code as an administrator...the text file I am outputting is present, with read write permissions...the ofs object is being created successfully)...

---

**Currently, totally out of ideas...** (tried linking lboost_serialization, reinstalling boost)  No idea if I am missing something from the code ^^^

Comment: I think you need to link to one of boosts libraries. This looks like linker errors.

Comment: @KurtStutsman thanks man.  I have tried -lboost_serialization; but I am having trouble figuring out what else to try.  Do you have any idea of where I can go looking for a listing/documentation of the possible linkages?

Comment: What's the command you're using to build? Can you add the entire command line to the question?

Comment: @KurtStutsman yup, this afternoon

Comment: @KurnStutsman  so this compiles everything fine when I comment out all boost; uncomment boost, and it all breaks: 

`g++ -std=c++11 -lboost_serialization main.cpp hashmap_transaction.h hashmap_transaction.cpp -o run.exe`

This is in Cygwin; tried `-lboost-serialization` just in case, and it could not find the linkage...

Comment: Never ever add an `.h` file to the compilation command.  `map<string transaction_hash, vector<DataUnit<T>> > hashmap;` is not legal C++. You also never reference `serialize` which is never instantiated. Please post your real code.

Comment: @n.m. it is my real code...just removed some methods. Sry if it is "illegal"?

Comment: @n.m. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468300/hashmap-of-vectors-in-c#8468310  seems possible.  instead of int, I've got: `DataUnit<T>`

Comment: @n.m. I followed the boost tutorial for `serialize`...this is what the boost library expects inside of an object that it will be serializing.  here is the tutorial link.  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

Comment: @n.m. as to compilation, I have literally no code in my .cpp file.  it is all in the header, because I didn't seem to need any.  So it is empty.

Comment: Illegal C++ means it will not compile (with errors different from those you claim). There are other errors like missing semicolons.Try to compile your code **as posted** and see for yourself.

Comment: @n.m. ok, fair enough.  The code is working at the moment. If you mean missing semi's at the close bracket...don't even get a warning.  There is no semi after `template<typename T>` but I'll go ahead and copy some stuff in that does compile.

Comment: I know what the tutorial says. Your code as posted doesn't follow the tutorial as there is no archive created and no object pushed to the archive.  Please read on [mcve] and make sure code **you post** with the exact same result you claim.

Comment: "don't even get a warning" You are not compiling what you think you are compiling then. C++ won't forgive you missing semicolons. Copy the code from your post and try to compile it.

Comment: @n.m.  It works; If I have a chance to debug what I wrote up there yesterday, I will.  But I can't afford the time at the moment, and I am not going to paste my actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the order of your dependencies on the build command like. You need to list dependencies after the modules that use them. Also you don't compile .h files. They should be included in the .cpp files that use them. Try this command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp hashmap_transaction.cpp -o run.exe  -lboost_serialization
```

Comment: ok, will try that...at the moment, reinstalling boost and building from tar rather than Cygwin install...

Comment: @bordeo Reinstalling boost and/or building from sources is **not** going to help. Might just abort the build now to save time.